# How to import locally generated addresses on my Metamask?

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Im currently creating a basic connect and fund contract where I will be able to fund an address using hardhat and ethers.js. I currently have a local mock created in my terminal with dummy accounts and private key's I copied one a pasted in here and I'm getting this major error on metamask!

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

i can give you stepwise solution
if its helpful please like it

step 1: go to vs code and find localhost chain id

> firstly check your default network is hardhat or not if not please
> change to hardhat

then find chain id using below code

```
  const provider=hre.ethers.provider;
  const chainId = await provider.getNetwork().then(network => network.chainId);
  console.log(`Chain ID: ${chainId}`);
```

step 2: find rpc url of you localhost blockchain

> run below command in you cmd to find rpc url
> check ss for reference

```
npx hardhat node
```

[image]

step 3: go to metamask and add network manually

> fill the below details

[image]

> after that add local account with your local privatekey

you can find privatekey from step 2

now you can check balance of the ether

[image]

i think now your problem has been solved

Comment: Thanks broski, but i have the current chain id included still it doesn't work, I want to try and re-deploy and see it it'll still work.